# Delete image from list in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list that you add images to using a simple add function.

I now need the option to delete a image in the list.

I have a simple button and a function I believed would work however I am, getting a error.

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined
```

**Question**

How do I fix my delete button so that I can remove the image from the list.

The add function is working, how do I fix the remove button.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" class="campaign-container">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{campaign.c_name}} {{$index}}</h1><strong>This Campaign you are allowed {{campaign.max_slots}} Images</strong>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select File</th>
                <th>Preview Image</th>
                <th>Add to list</th>
                <th>Images</th>
                <!-- <th>Remove Image</th>-->
                <th>Save Campaign</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- UPLOAD IMAGE-->
                    <div class="upload-new">
                        <input type="file"  fileread="vm.uploadme" id="fileinput-{{ $index }}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- PREVIEW IMAGE-->
                    <div class="preview">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{campaign.preview}}" alt="preview image">
                    </div>
                    <!-- END-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="addImage(campaign)">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size: 45px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots" class="slot">
                        <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="show image here">
                        <button ng-click="removeImage(slot)">Remove Image</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="SaveImage()">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size: 45px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $scope.addImage = function (campaign) {
        console.log('add in campaign', campaign);
        if (!campaign) {
            console.log('no campaign');
        }else {
            if (campaign.slots.length < campaign.max_slots) {
                campaign.slots.push({
                    "slot_id": $scope.length + 1,
                    "base_image": campaign.preview,
                    "path_image": ""
                });
            } else {
                window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            }
    }
    };

  $scope.removeImage = function (s,campaign) {
        campaign.slots.splice($scope.campaigns.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
    };
```

Comment: Hi, @Beep. Please note that the [tag:angular] is only for angular 2+. For angular 1.x question, use the [tag:angularjs] tag.

Comment: @n00dl3 thanks man, just fixed the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have typo error. in `$scope.campaigns`
try this

```
$scope.removeImage = function (s,campaign) {
    campaign.slots.splice(campaign.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
};
```

Comment: Wish it was just a type, unfortunately still get the error, +1 for the spot though.

Comment: instead of `($scope.campaign.slots.indexOf(s), 1)` do `(campaign.slots.indexOf(s), 1)`. just remove the $scope

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only one parameter in your `ng-click`: `ng-click="removeImage(slot)"`

But in your controller, you are accepting two:

```
$scope.removeImage = function (s,campaign) {
    campaign.slots.splice($scope.campaigns.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
};
```

As you never pass the `campaign` parameter, it is undefined.

So, you need to pass the second parameter from your HTML:
`ng-click="removeImage(slot,campaign)"`

Comment: hmm ok with this I get a new error lol `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: You are accessing `slots` of `campaigns`. The `slot` property is defined for each of the campaign and not the `campaigns` array.